# Indicative vs. subjunctive in "no importa qué dice el destino"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales, indicativa, letras-de-canciones

If I'm hearing it correctly, there's a line in Carlos Baute's "Colgando En Tus Manos" that says:

> No importa qué dice el destino.

I thought that sentence should be expressed:

> No importa qué diga el destino.

What is the difference between the indicative and subjunctive in sentences like this? When can the indicative be used instead of the subjunctive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't trust song lyrics since many times they are not grammatically correct. They just try to fix themselves to the melody. If you check [the lyrics](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=1279209) first he says the sentence twice but in both ways:

> **No importa qué diga el destino**
>
> We don't know yet what it has said. (Subjunctive for supposition), and it doesn't matter what Fate can say.
>
> **No me importa qué dice el destino**
>
> We already know what Fate has said and don't mind.

It's a bit weird knowing what Fate says, so I'd prefer subjuntive, in any of these ways:

> No importa lo que diga el destino.
>
> No importa qué diga el destino.
>
> No me importa qué diga el destino.
>
> No me importa lo que diga el destino.